# iOS WebKit - DataCloneError: The object can not be cloned

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

When working with WKWebView of iOS WebKit, I encountered an error when I tried to `postMessage` back to my `WKScriptMessageHandler` in a code like

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.thisHandler.postMessage(message);
```

where message is a Javascript object (or in iOS developer's eyes, a dictionary) and the error is:

```
WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=DataCloneError: The object can not be cloned.
```

It was quite confusing what this is about and I couldn't google out any useful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After removing the key-values one by one from my message object, I eventually figured out this error is caused by my mistakenly including some Javascript DOM objects instead of their primitive values in the object. For example, I included some variable

```
const myVar = document.body.querySelector("div.someClassName")
```

in my message body, which cannot be cloned for the native Swift environment. Similarly `window.location` is a purely JS DOM object and not clone-able either. To fix, just get their primitive values and include that in the message, like

```
const myVar = document.body.querySelector("div.someClassName").innerText;
const myURL = window.location.href;
const message = {myVar, myURL};
window.webkit.messageHandlers.thisHandler.postMessage(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for having a function in the message payload.